# What's the difference between $Df$ and $Tf$?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, dynamical-systems

I'm reading Michael Shub's Global Stability of Dynamical Systems.
In chapter 4, he defined hyperbolic set and said the splitting $E^s$ and $E^u$ are $Tf$ invariant. So I assume this $Tf$ is the derivative which is usually written as $Df$ in most dynamical system books. But in chapter 5, corollary 5.19, he used $Df$ as the derivative.
I'm really confused right now.

Comment: From what you have stated, I'm assuming his $Tf$ refers to a time derivative operator and $Df$ to a spatial derivative operator, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This book does not consider time derivative. I'm thinking maybe his $Tf$ is only used for points in the hyperbolic set, but $Df$ can be used for any points in the manifold? But I still don't understand why he doesn't just use $Df$.

Comment: Both $Tf$ and $Df$ are common notations for the derivative. So I guess that's the same...

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking the same thing. It's just really confusing he used both $Tf$ and $Df$ in the proof of corollary 5.19